MSSQL Dacpack publish error AllowMultipleExtensions
I am having issue with command while running dockerfile:
sqlpackage /a:Publish /tsn:localhost /tdn:${DBNAME} /tu:sa /tp:$SA_PASSWORD /sf:/dacpac/...
My colleagues don't have issue. I am only one with arm mac. They use WSL and our linux machine works also just fine.
I am running docker build with platform linux/amd64.
Info from build log:
Waiting for SQL Server to be ready...
SQL Server is ready.
Publishing to database '****' on server 'localhost'.
Initializing deployment (Start)
Initializing deployment (Failed)
Time elapsed 0:00:00.37
*** An unexpected failure occurred: 'AllowMultipleExtensions' property specified was not found..

I don't even know what "AllowMultipleExtensions" is.
Database project is NET.Framework build in mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 image
Database image is mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

I just experienced this as well, and downgrading the version of sqlpackage seemed to work for me. My use case is a little different as I'm using bacpac files.
The specific version that is working for me can be found at https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/8/eb8fd935-e9c6-497f-9d71-1af3dc301e4e/sqlpackage-linux-x64-en-162.1.167.1.zip
I found that using the latest version was causing the error message.

Hi, thank you for your response. This worked for me as well, thank you.
